# java GET method doesn't work

Tags: java, cookies, get, httpclient, urlconnection

I wanted to write get request for one site (). but when I do it, it says me: "Oops! If you are seeing this, your browser isnot loading the page correctly. Please try pressing Control-F5 to force reloadthe page." I don't understand why. I just copied request from my browser (google-chrome). I got 200 response. How can I fix it ? thanks!

code:
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample2 {

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://www.interpals.net";
    HttpUrlConnectionExample2 http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample2();
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
    String page = http.sendGet(url);
    if (page.contains("Oops")) {
        System.out.println("HAS OOPS");
    }
}

private String sendGet(String link) throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);
    request.addHeader("user-agent", USER_AGENT);
    request.addHeader("method", "GET");
    request.addHeader("path", "/index.php");
    request.addHeader("scheme", "https");
    request.addHeader("version", "HTTP/1.1");
    request.addHeader("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    //request.addHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
    request.addHeader("accept-language", "ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6");
    request.addHeader("cache-control", "max-age=0");
    request.addHeader("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + link);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " +
            response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
    return result.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: possibly the page runs a javascript defence and if javascript engine isn't present, then this could possibly be the <noscript> version of the page